# Why we need to load chilkat lib using static block

Tags: java, csv, chilkat

Recently i had a task to read and update a specific cell in a csv for that i used chilkat csv libs.
But what i dont understand is why we need a static block to load the chilkat library even after adding the jar file to Reference library in Eclipse project.

The below is the static block code used

```
static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("chilkat");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
        System.err.println("Native code library failed to load.\n" + e);
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do load the library when this particular class is *initialized*, then you use *static blocks*. This prevents *lazy loading* of the library (when it is first accessed). Loading it early (i.e, in a *static block*) increases program *responisveness* during *runtime*.

Note : Adding the jar file to Reference library doesn't *loads* the library *lazily* i.e, the dependencies will be loaded as and when needed *after they are resolved* during build time.

Comment: Is there any way this can be achieved without using the static block. Because when i remove this static block its throws the below error               Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.new_CkCsv()J
 at com.chilkatsoft.chilkatJNI.new_CkCsv(Native Method)
 at com.chilkatsoft.CkCsv.<init>(CkCsv.java:39)
 at CsvOperations.GetIMEI(CsvOperations.java:22)
 at CsvOperations.main(CsvOperations.java:17)

Comment: @PatilPrashanth - You might want to google `UnsatisfiedLinkErrors` and see for yourself. Native libraries should be found and linked in your JVM